# usernames and passwords are not matched and program is not moving further

Tags: java, mysql-workbench

```
try {
    String pass = tf2.getPassword().toString();
    Connection myConn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/javaproject", "root", "noor1032");
    PreparedStatement myStat = myConn.prepareStatement("select*from user_info where username=? and password=?");
    myStat.setString(1, tf1.getText());
    myStat.setString(2, pass);
    ResultSet Rs = myStat.executeQuery();
    if (Rs.next()) {
        f.dispose();
        new sharepage();
    } else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(f, "Invalid username or password", "Alert", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
} catch (Exception f) {
    f.printStackTrace();
}
```

this is what i have written in code....i want that program should match both username and password and then move forward......But this is not happening....In database i have usernames with corresponding passwords. Help me please!!!

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: there is no error....problem is that when i click on login it statement written in else statement is executed....i am not able to login

Comment: Well, `select*from` should be `select * from`

Comment: @JashandeepSingh do you see "Invalid username or password"?

Comment: yes i see invalid username or password on dialog box

Comment: What are tf1 and tf2? `java.awt.TextField`, `javafx.scene.control.TextField`, `javax.swing.JTextField`?

Comment: they are written in rest of the code....tf1 is textfield and tf2 is passwordfield

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
String pass = tf2.getPassword().toString();
```

with

```
String pass = new String(tf2.getPassword());
```

Why?

`JPasswordField#getPassword()` returns `char[]`, and `char[]#toString()` does not return a new String containing the characters from the char array. Instead it returns something like "[C@54bedef2".

The correct way of converting a `char[] cc` into a String is `new String(cc)`

Comment: thank you so much bro.....it started working......i am very grateful to you

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
myStat.setString(1, tf1.getText());
```

to

```
myStat.setString(1, tf1.getText().toString());
```

`getText()` returns `Editable` object and not `String`.